# unrolling a while loop

Tags: loop-unrolling

original code

```
while(i<30){
// do something
i++;
}
```

unrolled while loop

```
while(i<15){
// do something twice
i+=2;
}
```

Cant we unroll it as shown above. Do we always have to do it like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling ?

Comment: Try it and see. In particular, pay attention to the value of `i` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is no. It works for 30 and 15 because 30 is even, but it would not work as easily for odd numbers. ["Duff's device"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) was invented to deal with general case. It is quite ugly, though.

Comment: so then not only for while loops. For for loops too this matters if the iteration does not happen for even numbers right ?

Comment: @klijo This is correct: when the desired number of iterations is not a multiple of the number of times you unroll, you need to complete the remaining `n%k` iterations manually or in a tight loop without unrolling.